# Resque hates kaminari dsl method paginates_per

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dsl, resque, kaminari

So I'm converting my Admin mailers to use Resque and execute in the background.

When I ran:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*' --trace
```

I get this:

```
$ rake resque:work QUEUE='*' --trace (in /my/directory)
** Invoke resque:work (first_time)
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Execute resque:preload rake aborted! undefined method `paginates_per' for #<Class:0x000000045ba1b8>
```

which traces back to my Micropost model that default to 10 micropost per page using kaminari's dsl method paginates_per:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
.
  paginates_per 10
```

How do I get rake to stop puking without moving the DSL method?

Comment: I thought I didn't need to do:

Comment: I thought I didn't need to do: rake environment resque:work QUEUE='*' --trace if I had a task "resque:setup" => :environment

Comment: Actually, this really sucks resque:setup => :environment doesn't seem to really work